# C# - Value on first inserted object on the list change

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have 2 list.

1. List of Employee{int id, string name, string address}
2. List of Address { int empId, string address}

I want to have a record of Employees with different addresses base on the number of address in the Address List

The problem is that for example
emp 1 has 2 address
address 1 and address 2

when it added the 2nd address it also change the address on the first index

I have a sample code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ughoOW)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
        var temp = new Employee()
        {id = 1, name = "emp1", address = "address 1"};
        empList.Add(new Employee()
        {id = 2, name = "emp2", address = "address 3"});
        empList.Add(temp);
        List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();
        addresses.Add(new Address()
        {empId = 1, address = "address 1"});
        addresses.Add(new Address()
        {empId = 1, address = "address 2"});
        addresses.Add(new Address()
        {empId = 2, address = "address 3"});
        addresses.Add(new Address()
        {empId = 2, address = "address 4"});
        List<Employee> result = new List<Employee>();
        foreach (var item in addresses)
        {
            var tempRes = new Employee();
            tempRes = empList.Where(m => m.id == item.empId).First();
            tempRes.address = item.address;
            //var generated = generateEmp(emp,item.address);
            result.Add(tempRes);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("results");
        foreach (var res in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("empid : " + res.id + " address : " + res.address + " name : " + res.name);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("addresses");
        foreach (var res in addresses)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("empid : " + res.empId + " address : " + res.address);
        }
    }

    public static Employee generateEmp(Employee emp, string address)
    {
        Employee temp = new Employee();
        temp = emp;
        temp.address = address;
        return temp;
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public int id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string address
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public int empId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string address
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They are probably reference types: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-value-type-and-reference-type

Comment: It looks like you have to use GroupBy but know nothing about it) Or at least you should use search employer by their addresses empList.Where(m => m.Address == item.Address).First(). But it still looks strangely. Why you don't add List of addresses to Employer?

Comment: If you use the debugger you will find that `tempRes = empList.Where(m => m.id == item.empId).First();   tempRes.address = item.address;` this modify the entry in `empList`. The First iteration will return `{id = 1, name = "emp1", address = "Employee address 1"}` and after the second time `{id = 1, name = "emp1", address = "Employee address 2"}`. And when you do `result.Add(tempRes);`, you add a reference to the first item in `empList`. When you display the result it simply follow the reference and display the value fo the first item

Comment: One solution will be to handle those 2 original list as "Sql Table", and go for a simple inner join like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins, the end result will look like this.

Comment: @Lana changing the loop will also show the weird problem that it will update the first item

Answer (score 1):

> Above scenario Employee List address property each time you override from another Address class that's why shows last address of both record for the same employee

### Sample Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
        var temp = new Employee() { id = 1, name = "emp1", address = "address 1" };
        empList.Add(new Employee() { id = 2, name = "emp2", address = "address 3" });
        empList.Add(temp);
        List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();
        addresses.Add(new Address() { empId = 1, address = "address 1" });
        addresses.Add(new Address() { empId = 1, address = "address 2" });
        addresses.Add(new Address() { empId = 2, address = "address 3" });
        addresses.Add(new Address() { empId = 2, address = "address 4" });
        List<Employee> result = new List<Employee>();
        foreach (var item in addresses)
        {
            var tempRes = new Employee();
            tempRes = empList.Where(m => m.id == item.empId).First();
            tempRes.address = item.address;
            //var generated = generateEmp(emp,item.address);
            result.Add(tempRes);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("results");

        foreach (var res1 in addresses)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("empid : " + res1.empId + " address : " + res1.address + " name : " + empList.Where(m => m.id == res1.empId).FirstOrDefault().name);
        }


        Console.WriteLine("addresses");
        foreach (var res in addresses)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("empid : " + res.empId + " address : " + res.address);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static Employee generateEmp(Employee emp, string address)
    {
        Employee temp = new Employee();
        temp = emp;
        temp.address = address;
        return temp;
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public int id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string address
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public int empId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string address
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```